# How to iterate over an AngularFire observable list?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

How do you iterate properly over an AngularFire observable list?
I'm not sure how to handle the data as each response returns all the members of the list plus a new one (like a "pyramid") -

```
first response: [{obj1}]
second response: [{obj1}, {obj2}]
third response: [{obj1}, {obj2}, {obj3}]
```

I tried to implement two solutions in my code, none of them seem like the right way to go.

The first solution uses rxjs map - but it's too excessive, as it iterates over the entire response each time.

```
getAllSchools(): Observable<any> {
    return this.angularFire.database.list('schools').map((response) => {
        return response.map(school => {
            return \\do something to school\\
        })
    })
}
```

That means that in the example above (which iterates over `schools` list) the "*do something to school*" would be executed to `school1`, then again to `school1`, and first time to `school2`. Then third time to `school1`, second time to `school2`, and first time to `school1`, etc.

Second solution that I tried to implement was using `preserveSnapshot`. The problem here is that I'm not positive that it returns each piece of data one time and one time only.

```
getAllSchools(): Observable<ISchool> {
    return new Observable(observer => {
        this.angularFire.database.list('schools', { preserveSnapshot: true })
            .subscribe(snap => {
                snap.forEach((school) => {
                    ///do things to school///
                    observer.next(school)
                })
            })
    })
}
```

It's a very fundamental question and I'm sure that the solution is very "simple". Nonetheless, I couldn't find a clear cut solution.

Is it necessary to use another library, such as this [one](https://github.com/OasisDigital/angular2-firebase-demo)?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Sounds like this issue: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/574

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved by angularFire very latest version update (just a week ago). After running "npm i angularfire2@next" ("angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.7.1-pre"), all works fine.

for more -  https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/574